# Vue components not reactive to change in array

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

My Vue instance has an array of Vue components:

```
let vm = new Vue({
  el: '#maze',
  data: {
    tiles: []
  },
```

The components populate the DOM properly per:

```
<truchet-tile v-for="tile in tiles" v-bind:key="tile.id" v-on:click="tile.rotate()">
    </truchet-tile>
```

I initialize the array using `.push()`.

When I inspect the array, it's all set up correctly, however the Vue components have their initial/default values, all 0: (`id` should be 2 here, and `ttype` a random number between 0 and 6)
[image: DOM components and their keys are correct]

The data (`ttype`) in each component remains 0. I can't figure out why it's not reacting.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/facechomp/gwe2f1ds/123/).

Comment: You have two nested divs with same id `id="maze"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwe2f1ds/126/), you'll see your code work as intended (or atleast how I understood it). The main issue was that you were creating the array of `tiles` with generic objects. These objects don't automatically transform to `truchet-tiles` with the needed properties.

What needed to be done was passing the properties to each instance of `truchet-tile`. Next thing what needed to be done was to move the `v-on:click` handler. You want the `rotate` method to fire when a user clicks on the `truchet-tile`. But since an instance of `truchet-tile` eventually becomes an `img` (because of the `template` attribute), we need the handler on this `img` instead.

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask

Comment: The JSfiddle link is dead now.